# Base locus of vector bundles on K3 surface with positive $c_1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective K3 with $\mathrm{Pic}(S)\cong\mathbb{Z}\cdot H$ and $H^2=2rd$.  Suppose $E$ is a stable vector bundle with Mukai vector $v=(r,c,c^2d)$ where $c>0$ and $\gcd(r,c)=1$. Can one say anthing about the base locus $$\{p\in S \mid H^0(S,E)\to E(p) \mbox{ is not surjective}\}$$
of $E$? In particular, is it possible for the base locus to be $S$?

Thanks in advance!